# word/excel base64 embedded in iframe is auto downloading instead of displaying in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have embedded the base64 of word and excel files in iframe its auto downloading instead of displaying. for pdf and text base64 are displaying in iframe. Please advise here.

Comment: is your browser capable of natively showing word or excel files?

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you very much for comment. Let me give details on my application. I am working on offline application . browser will not support any api or officeviewer or google docs to view the documents. I am playing with attached file base64 to display and download in application

Comment: *in application* - you mean Word or Excel, or do you mean in your *offline application*

Comment: in my offline application

Comment: which is a web page? and you want to `display` it in this web page?

Comment: Yes, Sir. its offline web application. i have a word file base64. this needs to display in iframe .

Comment: so, ... the first question stands ... does your browser have the native ability to display word/excel files  ... modern browsers have the ability to natively display PDF's, so there's not mystery that PDF's work - the question remains ... **does your browser have the native ability to display word/excel files** - the answer is **no** so ... you **can't** display word/excel files in an iframe